# Posicionar registro seleccionado en combox en Jsp

Tags: java, jsp

Cordial saludo equipo necesito preguntarles lo siguiente, tengo el siguiente código en jsp, el cual tiene como objeto traer los registros que provienen de una base de datos en Mysql, el código es el siguiente:

```
<%@page import="javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.TryCatchFinally"%> 
<%@page language="java" contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<%
 String vid=null;  
 if(request.getParameter("cbovid")!=null){    /* cbovid  es el combobox*/
   vid=request.getParameter("cbovid");
  }
try{
            Connection cn=null;
            Statement cmd=null;
            Statement cmd2=null;  
            ResultSet rs=null;
            ResultSet rs2=null;  
          //1ra Etapa registrar el Driver
            String usuario="root";
            String password="";  
            String basedatos="nombredelabasededatos";
            String servidor="localhost";  
            String puerto="numerodelpuerto";   
            String url="jdbc:mysql://"+servidor+":"+puerto+"/"+basedatos;
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            cn=DriverManager.getConnection(url,usuario,password);
            cmd=cn.createStatement();
            cmd2=cn.createStatement();
          
            String sql2="Select * from herramientas";
            rs2=cmd2.executeQuery(sql2);
%>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="beige">
        <h1>Listado_de_Videos</h1>
        <hr>
        <form action="" method="post">
            <table width="50%" border="0">
                <tr>
                    <td width="33%">Seleccione Video:  </td>  
                    <td width="42%">
                       <select name="cbovid" id="cbovid" onchange="submit()">   <!--  cbovid  es el combobox - ->
                      
                       <% while(rs2.next()){%>
                                           
                       <option value="<%=rs2.getString(1)%>"><%=rs2.getString(2)%></option>   
                                                                      
                      <%}%>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td width="25%"> </td>
           </tr>
         </table>
      </form>
```

Al ejecutar el código y seleccionar un registro del combobox este no me aparece fijo dentro del listado sino que el combobox siempre me muestra el primer registro seleccionado del combox, agradezco me indique como arreglar dicho inconveniente
Gracias anticipadas.

Answer (score 0):

El problema que tienes es el `submit` que llamas en el evento `onchange`, al hacer eso cada que seleccionas un elemento en el combo se recarga la página y vuelve a seleccionar el primer elemento.
Sí solo quieres mostrar la página con el combo retira ese evento

Comment: Muchas gracias, el inconveniente es que si quito el evento onchange del combobox como usted dice si se me muestra el registro seleccionado pero no me muestra ni me actualiza la tabla con los datos que debe de traer.